# How can I update monthly data after connecting Tableau with a table which I created using 'into' statement?

Tags: tableau-api

I created a table for eg:

```
select * into Xtable  
from Ytable
union  
select * from  Ztable where serviceyear >= '12/1/2020.
```

Then I connected Xtable with Tableau.  Does Xtable update every month in the SQL server? How to update in the tableau work book every month?

Comment: When you say Tableau, do you mean Tableau Desktop for your own activity or Tableau server/online for shared dashboards?

Comment: Tableau desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a table called Table in a SQL Server database, then you will need to automate loading the table with additional data over time.  Otherwise, it only contains the data that you inserted at a single point in time.

SQL Server comes with a SQL Server agent which can be used to schedule running SQL Server agent jobs.  You could automate running your insert statement with this solution.  Alternatively, you can automate running your SQL script from a local workstation or server through endless numbers of methods.

Please note you won't be able to run SELECT * INTO as in your example each time. This syntax is used to create a table.  Unless you drop the table before running the command, you will need to use an INSERT INTO Xtable SELECT * FROM YTable UNION ... instead.

If you don't have a method for loading the data into the underlying SQL Server table, then you could create a view instead of a table.  The view could use the same definition as your insert statement and it will automatically show new data as data is appended to either Ytable or Ztable.

If you are using a live query for your data source, then Tableau will show the most recent data when you load the workbook.  Depending upon your caching settings, you may need to click the Refresh button in Tableau Server or refresh the data source in Tableau Desktop.

If you are using an extract, then you can schedule an extract refresh in Tableau Server or manually refresh the extract locally.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I also have a plan to use custom query. Not sure whether it updates monthly data  or not.

Comment: I cannot use view since the SQL statement has delete clause.

Comment: Tableau custom SQL doesn't support inserting into tables.  You can use Initial SQL to load a table beforehand, but initial SQL executes every time the query runs, so that would be very bad in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks. Will try.